# Logback - set threshold by logger

Tags: filter, logback, appender

I would like to configure rate limit for log lines per logger (for example: each logger can send max of 100 log lines per minute).

I had thoughts, shall I do it with a new simple filter (I don't think TurboFilter is appropriate)? Or a new appender?
Filter sounds more appropriate, but other filters can override my decision, that's why I think to implement it with appender.

Do you have any Ideas?

Comment: Just in case you solved this yourself, it would be awesome if you could post a self-answer, or at least a comment with some pointers. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've wrote my own filter. it looks like this:

```
public class ThresholdFilter extends Filter<ILoggingEvent> {
private final Cache<String/*Logger*/, AtomicInteger> loggerRates = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .expireAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();

@Override
public FilterReply decide(ILoggingEvent event) {
    return (isStarted() && (getLimit(event.getLoggerName()) > 100)) ? FilterReply.DENY : FilterReply.NEUTRAL;
}

private int getLimit(String loggerName) {
    int i = 0;
    try {
        i = loggerRates.get(loggerName, () -> new AtomicInteger(0)).incrementAndGet();

    } catch (ExecutionException ignored) {
    }
    return i;
}  }
```

And then added this filter to my appenders in the logback.xml

`<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
<filter class="org.ahiel.ThresholdFilter">
<encoder><pattern>[%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</pattern></encoder>
</appender>`

Comment: This is great, except I think you mean `expireAfterWrite` rather than `expireAfterAccess`.